# Cumulative for loop with conditionals

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, loops

I'm trying to do a for loop so that each iteration takes into account the result of the previous iteration. Specifically, I start with a definition (let's say `\newcommand\start{(0)}`) and then I enter the loop. I check a condition (via `\ifnum`) and if positive I redefine `\start` so that it gives `(0)--(ok)`. Then a new iteration and if the `\ifnum` is still positive, I redefine `\start` adding the new text `--(ok)` to the previous one `(0)--(ok)`, so that overall it gets `(0)--(ok)--(ok)`. And so on. This is my code.

```
\newcommand\start{(0)}
\newcommand\step{ }

\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
\pgfmathparse{random(1,3)}

\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
\renewcommand\step{\start --(ok)}
\else
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=2
    \renewcommand\step{\start --(yes)}
    \else
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=3
        \renewcommand\step{\start --(no)}
        \fi
    \fi
\fi

\renewcommand\start\step
}

\start
```

Of course it doesn't work. I tried to use `\def`, `\let`, etc. instead of `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`, but the result does not change, even if I admit that I am not an expert on these commands. I would like to avoid using packages like `etoolbox`, `ifthen`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do but I wonder whether you want to use the `remember` key in the `\foreach` statement: `\foreach \i [remember=\i as \step (initially 0)] in ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by `\renewcommand\start\step`.

- Firstly, since the loop body of `\foreach` is executed inside a TeX group, here you need to use global assignment to save the change to `\start` after every execution of loop body.
- Then, you also need to define `\start` as the (fully) expansion of `\step`, otherwise there would be infinite loop between `\start` and `\step`.

To sum up, change

```
\renewcommand\start\step
```

to

```
\xdef\start{\step}
```

Here `\xdef` can be seen as a shortcut of `\global\edef`.

---

In the following full example, I also change the nested `\ifnum ... \else ... \fi` to a `\ifcase ... \or ... \or ... \fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\start{(0)}
\newcommand\step{ }

\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {%
  \pgfmathparse{random(1,3)}%
  %
  \ifcase\pgfmathresult
  \or
    \renewcommand\step{\start -- (ok)}%
  \or
    \renewcommand\step{\start -- (yes)}%
  \or
    \renewcommand\step{\start -- (no)}%
  \else\fi
  %
  \xdef\start{\step}%
}

\start
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not give a complete code. I guess you use the `\foreach` inside a `path`, if so, you need to put the extra code such inside `\pgfextra`. Here is an example code. As @muzimuzhi Z says, you need to use `\xdef`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{arrows}{draw}{
\state{draw}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
  \path [every arrow subpath/.try] \pgfextra{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
   };
}}
\tikzset{
  c/.style={every coordinate/.try},
  every arrow subpath/.style={->, draw, thick}
}
\def\temp{(o)}
\def\addtotemp#1{\xdef\temp{\temp#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (o) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (yes) at (-1, 1);
  \coordinate (no) at (0, 2);
  \coordinate (ok) at (1, 1);
  \foreach \r in {0, 4, 8} {
    \def\temp{(o)}
    \draw[every coordinate/.style={yshift=\r cm},
      decoration=arrows, decorate,
    ] ([c]o) node[below] {o}
      \foreach \i [
        evaluate = \i as \random using {random(1, 3)},
      ] in {1, ..., 5} {
        \pgfextra{\typeout{xyz \temp}}
        \ifnum\random=1
          \pgfextra{\addtotemp{ -- (yes)}}
          to[->] ([c]yes) node[left] {yes}
        \else\ifnum\random=2
          \pgfextra{\addtotemp{ -- (no)}}
          -- ([c]no) node[above] {no}
        \else
          \pgfextra{\addtotemp{ -- (ok)}}
          -- ([c]ok) node[right] {ok}
        \fi\fi
      };
    \node[yshift=\r cm] at (0, -0.5) {\temp};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]